# SIGABRT signal when calling Parse Facebook login

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, swift2

I'm creating my first iOS app and experience some troubles with Parse Facebook login. After I successfully set up Parse login, I decided to add Facebook login button. I followed instructions from Parse:
I enabled Facebook Authentication in Parse settings, added my app to Facebook, edited info.plist file to add FacebookAppID, FacebookDisplayName and URL type. I build app with Xcode 7.0.1, app is written on Swift 2.0. I use latest Facebook SDK version 4.7.0 and latest Parse SDK version 1.9.0
When I run the app and try to login with Facebook, it crashes, returning SIGABRT signal.
At the same time I can see in Facebook statistics that it tracked app call.
The reason is this part of code:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile","email"],       block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            if user!.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            print("Uh oh. There was a problem.")
        }
    })
```

And here is the threads of error:
[Error threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkvCB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out mistake: `PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)` was missing in the AppDelegate file.